# How to execute process on remote machine, in C#

Tags: c#, process, system.diagnostics

How can I start a process on a remote computer in c#, say computer name = "someComputer", using System.Diagnostics.Process class?

I created a small console app on that remote computer that just writes "Hello world" to a txt file, and I would like to call it remotely.

Console app path: c:\MyAppFolder\MyApp.exe

Currently I have this:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Format(@"\\{0}\{1}", someComputer, somePath);

            startInfo.UserName = "MyUserName";
            SecureString sec = new SecureString();
            string pwd = "MyPassword";
            foreach (char item in pwd)
            {
                sec.AppendChar(item);
            }
            sec.MakeReadOnly();
            startInfo.Password = sec;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            Process.Start(startInfo);
```

I keep getting "Network path was not found".

Answer (score 17):

Can can use PsExec from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

Or WMI:

```
object theProcessToRun() = { "YourFileHere" };

ManagementClass theClass = new ManagementClass(@"\\server\root\cimv2:Win32_Process");

theClass.InvokeMethod("Create", theProcessToRun);
```

Comment: I posted a CW answer quoting MSDN on the Process class that you should incorporate into your answer to cover the question on using Process.

Comment: tks for your answer? By the way, do you know if SysInternals have full official support by microsoft?

Comment: Btw, "YourFileHere" needs to be the path local to the server, and you can append parameters to it, e.g. "C:\\Whatever\\Whatever.exe -param1 -param2" and "server" in that string needs to be the actual server name or ip, e.g. "\\localhost\root\cimv2:Win32_Process"

Comment: Some WMI authentication tips in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10414095/12484

Comment: Am I missing something with this one? When I try executing the first line `object theProcessToRun() = { "YourFileHere" };` with a path to the file, there are just loads of errors (cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration...) Have you already initialised something with `theProcessToRun()`?..

Comment: @Bassie Yeah - saw that, too - added an edit that hopefully will get accepted.  It should be `object theProcessToRun = new[] { "YourFileHere" };`, instead.

Comment: @ live2 Making code changes to answers is generally frowned upon,  especially in the case of an 8 year old answer. A better approach would be to post a new answer that expands on this one by updating the code to current environments - and of course, offering your additional solution.

Comment: I have tried WMI for launching remote process. They work perfectly fine for the local system. However, when then processes are launch on a remote system, they run only in the background and NOT interactively. I am searching for an alternate solution. Please share if you know.

Answer (score 15):

Use one of the following:

- (EDIT) Remote Powershell (feel free to use [System.Management.Automation.PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0))
- WMI (see Ivan G's answer)
- Task Scheduler API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- PsExec
- [WshRemote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9t3ze5y(v=vs.84).aspx) object with a dummy script. Chances are, it works via DCOM, activating some of scripting objects remotely.

Or if you feel like it, inject your own service or COM component. That would be very close to what PsExec does.

Of all these methods, I prefer task scheduler. The cleanest API of them all, I think. Connect to the remote task scheduler, create a new task for the executable, run it. Note: the executable name should be local to *that* machine. Not \servername\path\file.exe, but c:\path\file.exe. Delete the task if you feel like it.

All those methods require that you have administrative access to the target machine.

`ProcessStartInfo` is not capable of launching remote processes.

Comment: Do Task Scheduler for preference. See this answer for an illustration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178437/start-remote-process-within-the-context/8818377#8818377

Comment: Another option that can be useful if the target machine is a SQL server, is xp_CMDShell

Answer (score 7):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx), a `Process` object only allows *access* to remote processes not the ability to start or stop remote processes.  So to answer your question with respect to using this class, you can't.

Answer (score 4):

An example with WMI and other credentials as the current process, on default it used the same user as the process runs.

```
var hostname = "server"; //hostname or a IpAddress

var connection = new ConnectionOptions();
//The '.\' is for a local user on the remote machine
//Or 'mydomain\user' for a domain user
connection.Username = @".\Administrator";
connection.Password = "passwordOfAdministrator";

object[] theProcessToRun = { "YourFileHere" }; //for example notepad.exe

var wmiScope = new ManagementScope($@"\\{hostname}\root\cimv2", connection);
wmiScope.Connect();
using (var managementClass = new ManagementClass(wmiScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions()))
{
    managementClass.InvokeMethod("Create", theProcessToRun);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me if I have bat file on that machine stored somewhere. how can I execute that ? With Dynamic parameters.

Answer (score -5):

I don't believe you can start a process through a UNC path directly; that is, if System.Process uses the windows comspec to launch the application...  how about you test this theory by mapping a drive to "\someComputer\somePath", then changing your creation of the ProcessStartInfo to that?  If it works that way, then you may want to consider temporarily mapping a drive programmatically, launch your app, then remove the mapping (much like pushd/popd works from a command window).

Comment: I think that would just result in the local machine reading the remote executable, and running it locally.