# start remote process within the context

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I am wondering how to start process remotely within the users context like he started it. Let me explain. I know how to start process remotely, so for example I want to start notepad:

```
Invoke-WmiMethod win32_process -name create -ComputerName $remoteMachine -ArgumentList "notepad" -credential (Get-Credential)
```

the problem is that it starts notepad "in the backround" (not in the users context), so in this case he won't see opened "notepad" dialog/process (he will see notepad just in the list of processes in task manager). I want him to see notepad window dialog.

Does anybody know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot start interactive processes using WMI or PowerSHell remoting. This is a security limitation/feature. You need to use PSExec if you want to start remote interactive processes.

Comment: yes, thanks for reference the command working for me is:
.\PsExec.exe \\$remoteMachine -u $username -p $password -i -d "notepad"

Answer (score 11):

Use built-in SchTasks.exe for a supported way to create processes on a remote system. This interfaces with the built-in Task Scheduler service and does not require PsExec.exe.

To create a task on a remote machine (in this example running as SYSTEM):

```
schtasks.exe /create /F /S COMPUTERNAME /RU "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /RL HIGHEST /SC ONSTART /TN "RemoteProcess" /TR "program.exe \"argument 1\" \"argument 2\""

schtasks.exe /Run /S COMPUTERNAME /I /TN "RemoteProcess"

schtasks.exe /Delete /S COMPUTERNAME /TN "RemoteProcess"
```

Notes:

- We use ONSTART as the schedule, but then we start the process manually and delete it before the schedule is fired. This effectively means "just do it now". You could also specify `/SC ONCE /SD "01/01/1980" /ST "00:00:00"` which would have the same effect.
- This example is running as System. To run as the logged-in user, provided you know who that is use `/RU "DOMAIN\USER"`. This will work without a password (`/RP` option) if the user is logged in
  .
- You can use `/Query /S COMPUTERNAME /TN "RemoteProcess" /V` to find the current status e.g. to wait for exit and then read the exit code.

You can also do all the above with script using the Task Scheduler Scripting Objects:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383607(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: tip - add `/F` flag in the first command to avoid prompt of already exist in case of leftovers