# How to remotely backup registry file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I'm trying to backup a few registries remotely. I got this far (With some Google help), but, for these UNC paths, there is somewhere I need to enter logon/password credentials, as this didn't work. Can someone tell me where to edit?

```
echo ### Backing up the Registry...
if not exist "\\remoteserver\c$\registry" mkdir "\\remoteserver\c$\registry"
if exist "\\remoteserver\c$\registry.reg" del "\\remoteserver\c$\registry.reg"
regedit /e "\\remoteserver\c$\registry.reg"

Backup Complete!
@pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

- Establish a NETBIOS connection manually first.

Like this:

```
NET USE \\REMOTESERVER /USER:DOMAIN\USERNAME
```

You will be prompted for your password. This establishes a NetBIOS session with the remote server. You should be able to see the shared folders and shared printers on the remote server once you have done that.

- Start the process on the remote machine in the first place.

See this answer for a full explanation of how to do this using SCHTASKS.EXE:

- [start remote process within the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178437/start-remote-process-within-the-context/8818377#8818377)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ben. So from my desktop, i can run that in DOS first, then use the command as I pasted it originally? Start which process on the remote machine? NETBIOS?

Comment: @user1202223 the first choice, using `NET USE`, prevents you from having to enter your password. Then you can just use your existing code.