# Run application in separate session?

Tags: c, windows, session, windows-services

Someone can point me reliable method to run given application in different session of same user on Windows ?
I code in C.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to leverage Task Scheduler which can do this.

Use the method in this answer, but specify the local computer name, and a username and password:

[start remote process within the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178437/start-remote-process-within-the-context/8818377#8818377)

You should specify that it doesn't interact with the desktop.

Comment: So for example can i run team viewer via this method and to be able to work on the remote PC, without bothering the user that is working on it already ?

Comment: No! Absolutely not. This allows you to run programs invisibly without bothering the user. To run a second ***interactive*** session - i.e. one you can see and interact with - you need Terminal Services.

Comment: Isnt that what i am looking for -> http://chabster.blogspot.com/2008/01/run-as-interactive-user-from-service.html ?

Comment: @VisaToHell, No, that will display on the user's desktop. He will be able to interact with it but you will not. Really you need to script whatever it is you are doing so it can run unnattended.