# Run a Bat file in remote server without prompting for password

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have 2 windows servers (Let's say `Server1` and `Server2`). On `Server2` there is a batch file `server2.bat`. I need to execute that batch file on `Server2` from `Server1`. Hence I have created a `remote_run.bat` batch file in `Server1`.

`remote_run.bat` file having below code:

```
set machine=server2
set file=\\server2\c$\CI\server2.bat
set user=myuser
set userPwd=mypassword
set executeAs=%user%
set executeAsPwd=%userPwd%
schtasks /Create /S %machine% /U %user% /P %userPwd% /RU %executeAs% /RP %executeAsPwd% /SC ONCE /TN install /TR %file% /ST 00:00:00 /y
schtasks /Run /S %machine% /U %user% /P %userPwd% /TN install 
pause
```

If I run this script I will get below error

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '/y'.
Type "SCHTASKS /CREATE /?" for usage.
```

Then I removed /y in "`schtasks /Create /S %machine% /U %user% /P %userPwd% /RU %executeAs% /RP %executeAsPwd% /SC ONCE /TN install /TR %file% /ST 00:00:00 /y`" line then script throws error as below.

```
D:\>schtasks /Create /S server2 /U myuser/P mypassword /RU myuser
 /RP mypassword /SC ONCE /TN install /TR \\server2\c$\CI\server2.bat /ST 00:00:00
WARNING: Task may not run because /ST is earlier than current time.
```

Please check this code and help me to run a batch file in remote server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178437/start-remote-process-within-the-context/8818377#8818377   Once the task is created you need to run it, then delete it after.

Comment: To clarify, the warning you see is just to say that the task will not run at the scheduled time because you specified it to run at midnight, which has passed. This does not matter in your case because you are running it explicitly using the `/run` command. You should probably give the task a more unique name though.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks for the response. I am new to the DOS commands. I don't want to schedule the task just I want to execute bat file. Could you please provide the command for the same?

Comment: What you have is correct. First, schedule the task. Then run the task. Then delete the task. That is it.

Comment: @Ben: I ran that script, but it's not working properly even it's not failing. I have a psexec command to open command prompt "\PsExec.exe \\$remoteMachine -u $username -p $password -i -d "cmd.exe". but I want to run "net use" command in that command prompt. How can I pass "net use" command to above code?. Please help me