# Invoke-WmiMethod Command Not Displaying Application

Tags: powershell

This is strange. I'm executing this Powershell command to start a process on a remote server

```
#Invoke-WmiMethod –ComputerName SERVER1 -Class win32_process -Name create -ArgumentList "\\server1\c$\bss70\bss80.exe" -Credential $Cred
```

I can see the process running in task manager but the application is not displaying

[image]

Why is the application not displaying?

Comment: Processes started with Win32_Process aren't interactive. If you are looking to start a process interactively, the two most common workarounds are to create a schedule task and trigger it or use psexec.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [start remote process within the context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178437/start-remote-process-within-the-context)