# using PsExec to remotely open apps - task manager overloaded with process

Tags: c#

using this simple function i made in order to run applications remotely accross pc's on my network:

```
        private static void _remotelyOpenEXE(string psEpath, string ipv4LocalAdd, string userName, string passWord, string path)
    {           
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(psEpath, string.Format("\\\\{0} -i 1 -d -u {1} -p {2} {3}", ipv4LocalAdd, userName, passWord, path));
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
        Process.Start(psi);
    }
```

However, the issue is that everytime i run the program, this process keeps piling on top of each other:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm6xz.png)

trying to combat it, i tried killing all this process at the start of the function:

```
        private static void _remotelyOpenEXE(string psEpath, string ipv4LocalAdd, string userName, string passWord, string path)
    {
        foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (proc.ProcessName == "Execute processes remotely")
            {
                proc.Kill();
            }
        }     
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(psEpath, string.Format("\\\\{0} -i 1 -d -u {1} -p {2} {3}", ipv4LocalAdd, userName, passWord, path));
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
        Process.Start(psi);
    }
```

However, that wouldn't work as well.
it's not a major issue but i still find it unsettling, thanks in advance!.

EDIT: Looks like the problem is gone, could be a typo, had the problem for atleast few hours, suddenly it no longer occurs.

Comment: Don't use psexec to remotely  open apps. Use Task Scheduler. See my answer here for full details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178437/start-remote-process-within-the-context/8818377#8818377

Comment: Note that task scheduler is a supported component of windows. And it also can track the app and see if it is still running so you can know whether to start it a second time. Nobody should be using PSExec any more.