# How to run a command prompt on a shared server?

Tags: c#, command-prompt

I got a problem today, I'm developing a directory packager for my company. I want to install NSClient++ on 10 or 50 or 750 server in one click.

So I am using a `listview` where the user can add or delete a server. I have already copy the whole folder on each server in the list view but i have to install and start the `NSClient++` service, *so here is my question*:

How do I use a command prompt on network sharing servers ?

My application will be used from an admin server who can do anything on those servers, plus, I use this for directory copy :

```
DirectoryCopy(NSCP_Folder_Path, @"\\" + IP_server + @"\Program Files", true);
```

I hope I give you all the information you need to help me and if you want to know more, ask.

Comment: No need to be sorry for being french ;)

Comment: @AdrieanKhisbe I'm not sry for being french, i'm sry for my bad english :p

Comment: Je taquine juste  :)

Comment: [Try checking this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343677/how-to-execute-process-on-remote-machine-in-c-sharp)