# How to run a command line on a remote computer using C#

Tags: c#, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute a command in a remote computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428276/how-to-execute-a-command-in-a-remote-computer)

here is my question.

I have a remote computer LIQIANDEV and on it there is a command C:\test\test.cmd. Now I have a web server LIQIANTEST, I want to run the test.cmd on remote computer LIQIANDEV using C# code, how should I do this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Flag for Server Fault. Also @ColinGrealy is correct.

Comment: You need to write and install a server app on LIQIANDEV, then connect to it from LIQIANTEST

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428276/how-to-execute-a-command-in-a-remote-computer someone already asked a similar question some years ago, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a program on another computer using [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), which is part of Microsoft's SysInternals. Therefore, you could use c# to create a local process that runs the PsExec command.

Alternatively, you can use [Windows PowerShell Remoting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx) to run a powershell script on another computer. Once again, this could be kicked off using c#.

I think you can also do it with WMI or perhaps even RDP.

Answer (score -3):

Short answer: you can't. There are all kinds of barriers in place to prevent you from being able to do exactly that.

Longer answer: If you explain what you're trying to accomplish by running this code, there might be a better way to do it.