# How to send a Process.Start command over a local network (C#)

Tags: c#, network-programming

I'm 100% green when it comes to transferring data over a network... I've never done it before, and I have no idea what it entails. What I want doesn't seem like it would be too hard, however.

I have a very simple forms project in Visual Studio, just something I whipped up to sync up two media players. Basically, I need to open an application (With an argument) on my laptop by pressing a button on my desktop.

I know that to do it locally, I'd run...

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\MPC-HC\MPC-HC.exe", file);
```

So I'm just looking for a way to execute that command on my laptop via an app on my desktop.

Comment: you will need a tcp server on your laptop and a client on your desktop-pc, look up a basic tcp server/client example, there are a lot of those on the internet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428276/how-to-execute-a-command-in-a-remote-computer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287506/how-to-run-a-command-line-on-a-remote-computer-using-c-sharp?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

It depends on some things and some preparation on the WMI configuration, but Microsoft offers [a good start in the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on how to start a process remotely.

There's another simple solution, provided from the [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) tools. The [`psexec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) tool allows with some minor configuration the remote start of processes. This should be much easier for what you try to achieve.