# Using psexec to enable asp.net remote access with aspnet_regiis -config+ : File not found?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, psexec

I need to programatically enable remote config access to various servers that do not have remote access enabled.

I need to enable remote access, read the machine.config, and disable it again.

I'm trying to use psexec as outlined in this question's answers: [How to execute a command in a remote computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428276/how-to-execute-a-command-in-a-remote-computer)

However the `aspreg_iis -config+` command is returning a file not found error:

> psexec \\server "c:\...Net 4 path...\aspnet_regiis -config+"
>
> The system cannot find the file specified.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

If this is not supported, is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was embarrassingly simple: just omit the quotation marks:

> psexec \server c:...Net 4 path...\aspnet_regiis -config+

and it works fine.