# Run command on remote computer

Tags: c#, wmi, command-prompt, remote-server

I want to run a command in command prompt on a remote computer using C#. Per this link [How to execute a command in a remote computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428276/how-to-execute-a-command-in-a-remote-computer), I am trying to do this using the following code:

```
public static void RunRemoteCommand(string command, string RemoteMachineName)
{
    ManagementScope WMIscope = new ManagementScope(
        String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", RemoteMachineName));
    WMIscope.Connect();
    ManagementClass WMIprocess = new ManagementClass(
        WMIscope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
    object[] process = { command };
    object result = WMIprocess.InvokeMethod("Create", process);
    Log.Comment("Creation of process returned: " + result);
}
```

This returns an exit code of 0 and no errors are thrown, yet nothing is executed. Please help.

Comment: Are you aware which the `Create` method cannot be used to start an interactive process remotely?  try checking the task manager of the remote computer. You will see the process running but without GUI.

Comment: I see what you are talking about in task manager. Is there a way to add a parameter to the process? Specifically, if I create the process "cmd.exe", is there a way to pass that process a command so it can be run on a remote machine?

Comment: Try `cmd.exe /c foo.exe param1 param2`

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help

> http://www.petri.co.il/command-line-wmi-part-2.htm

Have a look into "Alternate Credentials" section. i believe you are able to do the little modification yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to try it out, [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) is great for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I know the post is old but for others who come across this page and also completeness:
RRUZ's comment is correct , but there is also one more thing you might need in order to run on the remote machine, credentials.
To do that you need to add connection options:

```
public static void RunRemoteCommand(string command, string RemoteMachineName, 
                                    string username,string password)
{


            var connection = new ConnectionOptions();
            connection.Username = username;
            connection.Password = password;


    ManagementScope WMIscope = new ManagementScope(
        String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", RemoteMachineName), connection);
    WMIscope.Connect();
    ManagementClass WMIprocess = new ManagementClass(
        WMIscope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
    object[] process = { command };
    object result = WMIprocess.InvokeMethod("Create", process);
    Log.Comment("Creation of process returned: " + result);
}
```