# Reflecting user action to another machine

Tags: .net

Today i got a task to create an utility to reflect user's action on a machine to another machine in network.

e.g.
If I open a IE on my machine then, IE should get opened on remote machine.
If I open a google.com on my machine then, google.com should get opened on remote machine.
If I search stackoverflow.com on my machine, then searching result should also get opened on remote machine.
mouse on movement on machine should also get reflected on remote machine

If anybody have idea, please share.

Comment: A simple reason why this would not work: what if the monitors have different resolutions? How would you cope with the mouse positions? And to continue, what if the Google accounts provide different results because of different logged in users?

Comment: Do you just want to have something like remote desktop where you're seeing the other machine's monitor? Because if not, what happens when (due to any of a wide range of circumstances) the *results* of performing the same actions on both machines don't match?

Comment: @AlexFilipovici: currently i am not thinking about resolution or hardware configuration, but your point is valuable i will think on it. But right now, please consider both the PCs with same configuration

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: remote desktop accesses remote machine's desktop to our monitor and in that, we have to do separate actions for each machine, i want to create a utility from which, action on one machine should get reflect to all the machines

Comment: Are you looking to create some kind of classroom software application?

Comment: @Stephen: Yes, do you have any suggestion

Comment: You don't want to replicate actions on the target machine, you want to share the desktop of the source machine. Different approach.

Comment: @Stephen: Ya, its a kind of sharing, but user will do action on only one machine, other machines will read user action and will process same action

Comment: No, you wouldn't want that. You want to `transmit` the `teacher desktop` to your `student desktops`. So you don't need to have the same software and specs on all the machines, and you will know the students see exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: @Stephen: You are right stephen, i need vice versa too. You think of a projector. But, projector will show my machine, and i want student should see their machine.

Comment: This is getting a bit lengthy in comments, but your approach should be to create a `teacher` application who can: 1. transmit the desktop to the clients 2. Take control of the clients 3. just observe the clients. Then you need a `student` application for the client machines, who will display the `teacher` desktop when the teacher initiates it, hand over control when the teacher initiates it, hand control back to the student when the teacher initiates it, and transmits it's own desktop to the teacher machine. Are you sure you want to build that yourself? There are plenty of solutions available.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35271/discussion-between-sandeep-gosavi-and-stephen)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17847654/2393573 Here, we can find how to call process on remote machine

Comment: Does anybody got any solution?