# Powershell - Copying File to Remote Host and Executing Install exe using WMI

Tags: powershell, copy, wmi, psexec

EDITED:  Here is my code now.  The install file does copy to the remote host.  However, the WMI portion does not install the .exe file, and no errors are returned.  Perhaps this is a syntax error with WMI?  Is there a way to just run the installer silently with PsExec?  Thanks again for all the help sorry for the confusion:

```
#declare params
param (
[string]$finalCountdownPath = "",
[string]$slashes = "\\",  
[string]$pathOnRemoteHost = "c:\temp\",
[string]$targetJavaComputer = "",
[string]$compname = "",
[string]$tempPathTarget = "\C$\temp\"
)

# user enters target host/computer
$targetJavaComputer = Read-Host "Enter the name of the computer on which you wish to install Java:"
[string]$compname = $slashes + $targetJavaComputer
[string]$finalCountdownPath = $compname + $tempPathTarget
#[string]$tempPathTarget2 = 
#[string]$finalCountdownPath2 = $compname + $

# say copy install media to remote host
echo "Copying install file and running installer silently please wait..."

# create temp dir if does not exist, if exist copy install media
# if does not exist create dir, copy dummy file, copy install media
# either case will execute install of .exe via WMII
#[string]$finalCountdownPath = $compname + $tempPathTarget;
if ((Test-Path -Path $finalCountdownPath) )
    {
    copy c:\hdatools\java\jre-7u60-windows-i586.exe $finalCountdownPath 
    ([WMICLASS]"\\$targetJavaComputer\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process").Create("cmd.exe /c c:\temp\java\jre-7u60-windows-i586.exe /s /v`" /qn")
    }
else {
    New-Item -Path $finalCountdownPath -type directory -Force
    copy c:\hdatools\dummy.txt $finalCountdownPath
    copy "c:\hdatools\java\jre-7u60-windows-i586.exe" $finalCountdownPath
    ([WMICLASS]"\\$targetJavaComputer\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process").Create("cmd.exe /c c:\temp\java\jre-7u60-windows-i586.exe /s /v`" /qn")
    }
```

Comment: Changed to an upvote to help you get some points to answer your own question. However, there is still a lot of unnecessary code here. If your problem is truly only in that one line, then you only need: `([WMICLASS]"\\$targetJavaComputer\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process").Create("cmd.exe /c c:\temp\java\jre-7u60-windows-i586.exe /s /v" /qn")`... What your expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing. And to run psexec "silently", use `-accepteula`

Answer (score 1):

**I was trying to get $Job = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -Scriptblock $Script to allow me to copy files on a different server, because I needed to off load it from the server it was running from.** I was using the PowerShell Copy-Item to do it. *But the running PowerShell script waits until the file is done copying to return.*

**I want it to take as little resources as possible on the server that the powershell is running to spawn off the process on another server to copy the file.** I tried to user various other schemes out there, but they didn't work or the way I needed them to work. (Seemed kind of kludgey or too complex to me.) Maybe some of them could have worked? But I found a solution that I like that works best for me, which is pretty easy. (Except for some of the back end configuration that may be needed if it is is not already setup.)

**Background:**
I am running a SQLServer Job which invokes Powershell to run a script which backups databases, copies backup files, and deletes older backup files, with parameters passed into it. Our server is configured to allow PowerShell to run and under the pre-setup User account with SQL Server Admin and dbo privileges in an Active Directory account to allow it to see various places on our Network as well.

**But we don't want it to take the resources away from the main server.** The PowerShell script that was to be run would backup the database Log file and then use the another server to asynchronously copy the file itself and not make the SQL Server Job/PowerShell wait for it. We wanted it to happen right after the backup.

**Here is my new way, using WMI, using Windows Integrate Security:**

```
$ComputerName = "kithhelpdesk"
([Wmiclass]'Win32_Process').GetMethodParameters('Create')
Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName RemoteServerToRunOn -Path win32_process -Name create -ArgumentList 'powershell.exe -Command "Copy-Item -Path \\YourShareSource\SQLBackup\YourDatabase_2018-08-07_11-45.log.bak -Destination \\YourShareDestination\YourDatabase_2018-08-07_11-45.log.bak"'
```

**Here is my new way using passed in Credentials, and building arg list variable:**

```
$Username = "YouDomain\YourDomainUser"
$Password = "P@ssw0rd27"   
$ComputerName = "RemoteServerToRunOn"
$FromFile = "\\YourShareSource\SQLBackup\YourDatabase_2018-08-07_11-45.log.bak"
$ToFile = "\\YourShareDestination\SQLBackup\YourDatabase_2018-08-07_11-45.log.bak"
$ArgumentList = 'powershell.exe -Command "Copy-Item -Path ' + $FromFile + ' -Destination ' + $ToFile + '"'
$SecurePassWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Username, $SecurePassWord
([Wmiclass]'Win32_Process').GetMethodParameters('Create')
Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName $ComputerName -Path win32_process -Name create -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Credential $Cred
```

We think that this above one is the preferred one to use.

**You can also run a specific powershell that will do what you want it to do (even passing in parameters to it):**

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -ComputerName RemoteServerToRunOn -Path win32_process -Name create -ArgumentList 'powershell.exe -file "C:\PS\Test1.ps1"'
```

This example could be changed to pass in parameters to the Test1.ps1 PowerShell script to make it more flexible and reusable. And you may also want to pass in a Credential like we used in a previous example above.

**Help configuring WMI:**

> I got the main gist of this working from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-wmimethod?view=powershell-5.1
>
> But it may have also needed WMI configuration using:
>
> https://helpcenter.gsx.com/hc/en-us/articles/202447926-How-to-Configure-Windows-Remote-PowerShell-Access-for-Non-Privileged-User-Accounts?flash_digest=bec1f6a29327161f08e1f2db77e64856b433cb5a
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-5.1
>
> [Powershell New-PSSession Access Denied - Administrator Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43190429/powershell-new-pssession-access-denied-administrator-account)
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-wmimethod?view=powershell-5.1 (I used to get how to call Invoke-WmiMethod).
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6  (I used to get syntax of command line)
>
> I didn't use this one, but could have: [How to execute a command in a remote computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428276/how-to-execute-a-command-in-a-remote-computer)

I don't know for sure if all of the steps in the web articles above are needed, I suspect not. But I thought I was going to be using the Invoke-Command PowerShell statement to copy the files on a remote server, but left my changes from the articles above that I did intact mostly I believe.

You will need a dedicated User setup in Active Directory, and to configure the user accounts that SQL Server and SQL Server Agent are running under to give the main calling PowerShell the privileges needed to access the network and other things to, and can be used to run the PowerShell on the remote server as well. And you may need to configure SQLServer to allow SQL Server Jobs or Stored Procedures to be able to call PowerShell scripts like I did. But this is outside the scope of this post. You Google other places on the internet to show you how to do that.