# Copy files to remote computer

Tags: powershell

As part of project requirement, I am preparing a script to copy the files from local computer to remote servers ( with username and password )

I have tried with below ways for files are 27 KB and 50 MB size

i. Using ReadallBytes and WriteAllBytes
    this is working for small file 27 KB, where as for 50 MB its taking 100% CPU and taking too much of time

```
$myfile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\Temp\test\a.txt")
$Stat = $null
$session=$null
$session = New-PSSession -computerName $server -credential $user
$Stat = Invoke-Command -Session $session -ArgumentList $myfile -Scriptblock {[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\temp\a.txt", $args)} -ErrorAction Stop
```

ii. I tried to copy with Copy-Item , but issue is target directory is not mount pointed

```
$Stat = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { Copy-Item -Path "C:\Temp\test\a.txt" -Destination "C:\temp\a.txt" -Recurse -Force -PassThru -Verbose } -Credential $user
```

Struck in both ways, please suggest any other way to achieve without mounting the target folder

Comment: Consider PowerShell's built in file transfer commands: `Copy-Item` or `Start-BitsTransfer`.  If you really need speed / find yourself dealing with much larger files, consider third party solutions such as TeraCopy (http://www.codesector.com/teracopy); though in the scenario you mention, this wouldn't be required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\Temp\test\a.txt" -Dest "\\$($server)\c$\temp\a.txt"
```

use the built-in drive shares to copy it over, you may need to provide creds for this.

you might find this helper function useful to get the remote path correctly.

```
Function Get-RemotePath($Server,$Path){
    "\\$($Server)\$($Path -replace ':','$')"
}

Get-RemotePath -Server "SERVER01" -Path "C:\Temp\File.txt"

\\SERVER01\C$\Temp\File.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why not use WMI top copy the file instead?**

It can be asynchronous and is very efficient.

I have a post here which explains it.

[Powershell - Copying File to Remote Host and Executing Install exe using WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24251355/powershell-copying-file-to-remote-host-and-executing-install-exe-using-wmi/51771578#51771578)