# Execute .bat File on a Server in C#

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to execute a `.bat` file on a remote machine (a server) that ends a process and kicks the user out of a database system. When executed on the server, the file works correctly and ends the process on the client machine.

However, when executed through C#, the command is entered into the command prompt and cannot execute. Here is the `.bat` file;

```
psexec \\lp-100 msg * Hi Dan - your being removed!

pskill \\lp-100 sdcdatabase.vshost.exe

pause
```

The issue arises when executed in C#, this is the error message:

[image]

What this leads me to believe is that actually the `.bat` file is not being executed on the server (that does have `PsTools` installed), but instead the contents is being copied over and executed on the client machine instead.

Here is the code I am using to execute the `.bat` file;

```
Process proc = null;
try
{
    string batDir = string.Format(@"\\hqdb1\sdc_sqldb\pstools\");
    proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = batDir;
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "removeuser.bat";
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();
    MessageBox.Show("Bat file executed !!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
}
```

Is this executing the `.bat` file on the server, kicking the client off, or executing on the client and not finding `PsTools`?

Comment: Its executing on the client.

Comment: @RonBeyer and how would I execute it on the server?

Comment: You are using PsTools, Use them to initiate/kill a process on remote machine. Read more about PsTools.

Comment: Not an answer, but you need to change the message to "You're", not "Your".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428276/how-to-execute-a-command-in-a-remote-computer

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I wrote this code, try if it's still working:

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Password = args[2];
options.Username = args[1];
string machine= args[0];

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope();
scope.Options = options;
scope.Path = new ManagementPath(@"\\" + machine + @"\root\cimv2");
scope.Connect();

ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name     = '" + args[3] + "'");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
{
    object y = m.GetPropertyValue("ProcessID");
    int pID = Convert.ToInt32(y);
    m.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
}
```